# How to draw two different possibility of query tree for the example? in ddbms

Tags: tree, ddms

```
select topic 
from book b, share s, stall st
where b.b#=s.b#
and st.store#=s.store#
```

I am trying to draw query tree I dont know how to draw query tree for above example.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a distributed database, you need to first know how your database is distributed before you can draw a query tree for it
ie. vertical (columns) and horizontal (values) distribution